# Disable varnish health check via varnishadm

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a varnish set up. I want to disable the backends in varnish, while updating the servers one by one. There is one way to do it, with health checks, but if my health check is every 20 seconds, there will still be 20 seconds downtime in the worst case. I found that through varnishadm I can set the health of a backend. For example:

```
varnishadm backend.set_health backend1 sick
```

The problem is that, when I do this, varnish still sends health check and sets the backend as healthy. Is there a away to disable temporally the health check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's the output of `varnishadm backend.list`

mine is like this one:

```
varnish> backend.list
200
Backend name                   Admin      Probe
84941fd7f319.default           probe      Healthy 4/5

varnish> backend.set_health default sick
200

varnish> backend.list
200
Backend name                   Admin      Probe
84941fd7f319.default           sick       Healthy 5/5
```

As you can see we first start with a healthy backend with probe enabled, we than mark it as sick and it will be considered sick  from an admin PoV, but some sort of probe record will still available.
What matters most is that no request will be hand out to the backend mark as sick.

Comment: Ah, actually it works. I have no idea, why it didn't work the previous times i did it. Thanks.